# Jquery Live function not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

My script Code

```
$(function () {
    $(".ui-button-text").live("click", function () {
        var buttonName = $(this).text();
        if (buttonName == 'Continue') {
            $("#runloGc").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Html code

```
  <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span></button>
```

Comment: live() is deprecated.

Comment: This has been asked a millions times. [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has beed REMOVED in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: It probably is "not working" because you are attaching to the click event of a span _inside_ a button, and the button click event is likely what gets fired/captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your updated code, you should bind the event to the `button` not the `span`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/aYqYA/)**

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.ui-button', function () {
 // code
});
```

Comment: No Omar not working this to, $(".ui-button").on("click",function(){ }); working in chrome not in firefox

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'button.ui-button', function () {` tested on firefox latest version 21.0. @SiddeshBhalke

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke welcome, glad to assist :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.live()` function is deprecated, try using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(function(){
    $(".ui-button-text").on("click",function(){
        var buttonName=$(this).text();
         if(buttonName == 'Continue'){
             $("#runloGc").prop("disabled",true);
         } 
     });
});
```

Or try like

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").on("click",".ui-button-text",function(){
        var buttonName=$(this).text();
         if(buttonName == 'Continue'){
             $("#runloGc").prop("disabled",true);
         } 
     });
});
```

Comment: .on() not working in chrome as well..!!

Comment: Should be something like `$("body").on("click", ".ui-button-text", function(){` or at least `$("div").on("click", ".ui-button-text", function(){`

Comment: @ShadowWizard Now I have added it too

Comment: you can also replace `$("input[type='button']")` with `$(document)`.

Comment: @Omar I will obey with you....we can give any of document,body,div,button,input,....blah blah

Comment: @Omar - that sort of defeats the purpose of `on` though, since now you are making it look through the entire DOM structure anyway - "jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached".

Comment: sorry guys not working above things as well..!! i added my html code..!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#container').on('click', '.ui-button-text', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
});
```

This will attach your event to any anchors within the `#container` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

This is the best case scenario. If you are not sure about the `container` element, you can use the `document` then like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-button-text', function(event) {
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtRGB/)

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/